# Jmeter: does jdbc preprocessor raise error to the Parent sampler?

Tags: exception, jdbc, error-handling, jmeter, preprocessor

I did a JDBC Preprocessor in a Parent Sampler. The JDBC Preprocessor executes a stored procedure: When the stored procedure fails the JDBC Preprocessor does not raise any error and the Parent Sampler does not fail too so the Thread continues to the next Sampler.
Why?

I tried to change the approach and instead of using the JDBC Preprocessor I used a new JDBC Request Sampler that executes the stored procedure before the original Parent Sampler. In this scenario the JDBC Request fails and the Thread stops.

Answer (score 0):

The main idea of the [JDBC PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_PreProcessor) is preparing the database for the execution of the JDBC Request sampler (or other Sampler)

If the preparation fails it's the Sampler who should fail. PreProcessor fails silently, you will only be able to see an entry regarding it in [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) file

If the Sampler doesn't fail on itself you can "help" it a little bit by adding a [Response Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-assertions-in-jmeter) and checking what it does return